# Attempting to display Am and Pm within UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker

I am attempting to display the UIDatePicker in the form of short style, which can be found in the documentation but I am not quite sure how, I did it manually using "hh:mm" however there was no Am or Pm tag so instead I attempted to do this

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = shortstyle
```

however it says that unresolved is an unidentified identifier.  Can someone show me what is wrong here and explain how to fix it, I am new to swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this code in the past to make a clock which is capable of telling AM or PM.

First, in the viewDidLoad I add:

```
myTimeLabel.text = ""

        _ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("updateClock"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Then in its own function:

```
func updateClock() {
        let date = NSDate()
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let components = calendar.components([.Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: date)

        //if statement if components hour > 12 then subtract 12 if not then leave it alone.
        var hour = components.hour > 12 ? components.hour - 12 : components.hour

        //this is an if statement if hour is = to 0 then 12 else it is equal to hour.
        hour = hour == 0 ? 12 : hour

        let hourString = hour > 9 ? "\(hour)" : "0\(hour)"
        let minutes = components.minute > 9 ? "\(components.minute)" : "0\(components.minute)"
        let seconds = components.second > 9 ? "\(components.second)" : "0\(components.second)"

        //this is an if statement if am is > then am is pm if < than it is am.
        let am = components.hour > 12 ? "PM" : "AM"

        myTimeLabel.text = "\(hourString):\(minutes):\(seconds) \(am)"

    }
```

I am not the origin of this code. I got it from an online course that I took a while back and am unable to find the first source of this code.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this although I was unable to find within the documentation that this was true I set dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a" and the a letter displayed either Pm or Am

Comment: @LeoDabus it says I cannot for two days, maybe this is because I am a new member?